# External Js file cannot run Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, external

My external js file (example.js):

```
alert("External js file has just been loaded !");

$("#start").click(function (e) {
    alert("Starting !");  
});
```

My HTML file has `<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>`.
When I load the page, it alerts `"External js file has just been loaded !"`, which means the js file is successfully loaded.

However, when I click to the Start button, it doesn't alert `"Starting !"`.

When I insert content of example.js file to the html file, it can alert `"Starting !"`:

```
<script>
    alert("External js file has just been loaded !");

    $("#start").click(function (e) {
        alert("Starting !");  
    });
</script>
```

How can I fix such a problem with the external js file?

Comment: Are you loading the example.js file before the #start element exists on the page? You should be loading the js file at the end of the page, or put the click handler within a document ready call.

Comment: @j08691 how can I load the js file at the end of the page?

Comment: Move `<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>` to right before `</body>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have injected your `jquery` script before your `example.js`.

For Example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
```

And check your console if you are getting any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Try loading `"example.js"` at `.ready()` using `$.getScript()`

```
$(function() {
  $.getScript("example.js")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this and everything seems to work fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#world-button").click(function() {
    alert("Hello World");
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="world-button">Hello World</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that I've embed the JQuery library just before `</body>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you have not written click event inside document.ready function. Events should be written when DOM is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").click(function (e) {
    alert("Starting !");  
  });
});
```

You can find more details here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/